# How to fix ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS using Laravel Middleware?

Tags: laravel

I am using Laravel 8 and when i redirect a route from middleware i am facing issue
**ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS**. I am verifying user with firebase otp and set cookie if otp verify then i want to redirect register page if user not exist in db. I have create middleware and check if cookie set then redirect to register route.

```
 public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
{
    if (Cookie::get('otpVerified')){
        return redirect()->route('register');
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

after that i am facing this issue
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kTLcu.png)
my route file is

```
Route::get('/register', [RegisterController::class, 'register'])->name('register_user');
Auth::routes();
Route::group(['middleware' => 'otpVerify'], function (){
Route::get('/404', [\App\Http\Controllers\ErrorController::class, 'notFound'])->name('404');
Route::get('/', [\App\Http\Controllers\Dashboard\DashboardController::class, 'index'])->name('dashboard');
});
```

How can i fix it. My kernel file is

```
 protected $middlewareGroups = [
    'web' => [
        \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
        \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
        // \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
        \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
        \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
    ],

    'api' => [
        'throttle:api',
        \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
    ],
];
```

and

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
    'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
    'cache.headers' => \Illuminate\Http\Middleware\SetCacheHeaders::class,
    'can' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
    'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
    'password.confirm' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\RequirePassword::class,
    'signed' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ValidateSignature::class,
    'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
    'verified' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\EnsureEmailIsVerified::class,
    'otpVerify' =>  \App\Http\Middleware\OTPVarification::class,
];
```

Comment: i think you have your conditional backwards

Comment: I can't understand.

Comment: @IrshadKhan is it one live server only ?

Answer (score 3):

In this section, you must exclude the register root

```
 public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
 {
     if (Cookie::get('otpVerified') &&  $request->route()->getActionName() !== 'YourRegisterAction'){
         return redirect()->route('register');
     }
     return $next($request);
 }
```

Comment: $request->route()->getActionName() !== 'YourRegisterAction'
 How can i handle this?

Comment: @IrshadKhan use dd($request->route()->getActionName()); on first of handle method and refresh register page to get this action name

Comment: Call to a member function getActionName() on null
Facing this issue

Comment: @IrshadKhan this works correctly for me, bet you can use this: if (Cookie::get('otpVerified') && strpos($request->requestUri, 'register') !== false)

Comment: $nextRequest = $next($request); I add this top and get achtion name but facing same issue

Comment: `$nextRequest = $next($request);

        if (Cookie::get('otpVerified') && $request->route()->getActionName() === 'App\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController@showRegistrationForm'){
            return redirect()->route('register');
        }

        return $nextRequest;`

Comment: @IrshadKhan add return $next($request) on top of handle method, still not working?

Comment: if i put return $next($request) it on top then how can i verify ?

Comment: i want to do this to see if this is the problem?, for testing only

Comment: Thank You soo much for your time i register middleware in kernel in route middleware section and apply individual its work

Comment: i suspicious this part:     if (Cookie::get('otpVerified'))